# Not able to show min and max value on x-axis in d3 js

Tags: d3.js

I ma using basic d3 js line graph. My Min and max values for x -axis are like

```
min = 128000 and max = 447916.09
```

Both values do not show up on x-axis. How do i make them show up? here is the piece of code i use to draw axis lines.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([min, max]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 25]).range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickValues([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]).orient("left");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis).selectAll("text").style("text-anchor", "end").attr("dx", "-.8em").attr("dy", ".15em").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
```

Comment: did you try to use `tickValues` also for the `xAxis`?

Comment: @jarandaf - I cannot hardcode values for a-axis.

Comment: Call `.nice()` on the x scale.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not able to see the x-axis is missing variables for width and height being declared and initialized in your source code.

```
var min = 500, max = 960;
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = max - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = min - margin.top - margin.bottom;`var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([min, max]).range([0, width]);  
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 25]).range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickValues([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]).orient("left");` `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");` ` svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")        
      .style("text-anchor", "end");` `svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Y Axis Tick Values");`
```